# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have class

```
@SuppressWarnings("JpaQlInspection")   
@Entity   
@Table(name = "tickets", indexes = {  
    @Index(name = "cancelation_Date", columnList = "cancelation_Date"),  
    @Index(name = "pos_id", columnList = "pos_id"),  
    @Index(name = "flag", columnList = "flag")  
})  
@SqlResultSetMapping(  
    name = "TicketMapping",  
    entities = @EntityResult(  
        entityClass = Ticket.class,  
        fields = {  
            @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "id"),  
            @FieldResult(name = "version", column = "version"),  
            @FieldResult(name = "pos_id", column = "pos_id"),  
            @FieldResult(name = "cancelation_date", column = "cancelation_date"),
            @FieldResult(name = "cost", column = "cost"),  
            @FieldResult(name = "flag", column = "flag"),  
        }  
    )  
)
```

---

```
public class Ticket extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "pos_id", length = 12)
    private String posId;

    @Column(name = "cost", length = 10)
    private String cost;

    @Column(name = "cancelation_date")
    private String cancelationDate;

    @Column(name = "flag", length = 10)
    private String flag;

    public String getPosId() {
        return posId;
    }

    public void setPosId(String posId) {
        this.posId = posId;
    }

    public String getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(String cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getCancelationDate() {
        return cancelationDate;
    }

    public void setCancelationDate(String cancelationDate) {
        this.cancelationDate = cancelationDate;
    }

    public String getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(String flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```

---

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "generator")
    @TableGenerator(name = "generator", table = "sequence_list", pkColumnName = "name", allocationSize = 50, initialValue = 3000)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public boolean isNew() {
        return (this.id == null);
    }
}
```

I'm using postgres 9.6. i got an error when:

```
Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(searchQuery,"TicketMapping");

return query.getResultList();
```

**error log:**

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1419) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.getResultList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at vn.com.bgt.lottery.dao.jpa.JpaTicketDao.search(JpaTicketDao.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at vn.com.bgt.lottery.TicketSearchUtil.search(TicketSearchUtil.java:89) ~[classes/:na]
    at vn.com.bgt.lottery.Console.exportTickets(Console.java:72) [classes/:na]
    at vn.com.bgt.lottery.Console.main(Console.java:59) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2618) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2153) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:991) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1410) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name id was not found in this ResultSet.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:2608) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar:42.0.0.jre6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2505) ~[postgresql-42.0.0.jre6.jar:42.0.0.jre6]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getLong(NewProxyResultSet.java:2625) ~[c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar:0.9.1.2]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:260) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:256) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:802) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:985) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:943) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.8.Final.jar:5.2.8.Final]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your query is not correct :

```
Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(searchQuery, "TicketMapping");
//--------------------------------------------------------------------^^
//This should be the ObjectName.class
```

So your query should look like this :

```
Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery("YourQuery", ObjectName.class);
```

Or just :

```
Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery("YourQuery");
List<ObjectName> list = query.getResultList();
return list;
```

Comment: thanks YCF_L . 2 case you support me: Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery("YourQuery");
List<ObjectName> list = query.getResultList();
return list; is ok . another case is the same error . Thanks for your help

Comment: Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery("YourQuery");  
List<Ticket> list = query.getResultList();  
return list; List here is not a list of Ticket . that is a list of object. when i try to cast to ticket i got error Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to vn.com.bgt.lottery.domain.Ticket

Comment: Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(searchQuery, "TicketMapping"); is Query javax.persistence.EntityManager.createNativeQuery(String sqlString, String resultSetMapping). i created @SqlResultSetMapping(  
    name = "TicketMapping" ... on the top of question .

Comment: i don't get you @HienVu ?

Comment: Hi YCF_L . Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery("YourQuery");
List<ObjectName> list = query.getResultList(); i can not access the list .

Comment: you have to change `ObjectName` with your object name @HienVu

Comment: i changed. but the query.getResultList() alway return object . not return my object ...

Comment: ah ok, how your query look like @HienVu ?

Comment: Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(searchQuery);
        List<Ticket> reulst = query.getResultList();
        return reulst;

Comment: yes i know know what `searchQuery` return @HienVu ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM tickets is searchquery

Comment: are you sure that you tried with `Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(searchQuery, Ticket.class); return query.getResultList();` and not work @HienVu?

Comment: sure YCF_L. i got the same error with the error log above

Comment: @HienVu are you sure that your query is correct it seams, that the name of your table is not match with the name of your entity, in your query it is `tickets` with `s` and your entity is without `s`?

Comment: @Table(name = "tickets", indexes = {
  @Index(name = "cancelation_Date", columnList = "cancelation_Date"),
  @Index(name = "pos_id", columnList = "pos_id"),
  @Index(name = "flag", columnList = "flag")
}). you mean the name tickets here ?  i removed {s} but got the same error.

Comment: Hi YCF_L, i use this code: Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery("YourQuery");
List<ObjectName> list = query.getResultList();
return list; an i got a list object . and loop into list object like this listTicket.stream().forEach((record) -> {
   (record[number].toString());
  }); thanks for you help .....

Comment: Query query = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(searchQuery, "TicketMapping"); I thinks my searchQuery is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

**change your result set with that one:**

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(  
    name = "TicketMapping",  
    entities = @EntityResult(  
            entityClass = Ticket.class,  
            fields = {  
                    @FieldResult(name = "version", column = "version"),  
                    @FieldResult(name = "pos_id", column = "pos_id"),  
                    @FieldResult(name = "cancelation_date", column = "cancelation_date"),  
                    @FieldResult(name = "cost", column = "cost"),  
                    @FieldResult(name = "flag", column = "flag"),  
            }  
    )  
)
```

as you error is telling you that you have a problem with the id. I think this will fix it for now.

Comment: Hi gen,Strash. i try but i dot the same error . Thanks